# Choosing random list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random

I would like to randomly choose list as whole
for example, I have lists with colors

```
list1 = ['blue','green']
list2 = ['red','yellow']
```

I have tried

```
random.choice(list1 or list2)
```

But it gives me random elemnt from them not the whole thing

Comment: `random.choice([list1, list2])`

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Please enter it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your example

```
random.choice(list1, list2)
```

but I was only getting an error. That's because `random.choice()` only accepts one argument - a sequence (a `list`). [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

Since you want to choose between two objects (`list`s), you have to make them into a sequence (e.g. `tuple`, `list`), and pass that into `random.choice()`:

```
random.choice([list1, list2])
```

Now it will choose either from the two elements `list1` and `list2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the list in another list, by doing either this:

```py
listcontainer = [list1, list2]
random.choice(listcontainer)
```

or this, which is simpler:

```py
random.choice([list1, list2])
```

The second option creates a new list (not assigned to a variable), that you can use in random.choice.